# Changing the RailsAdmin url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

in using RailsAdmin, is there a way to change the url from my_app/admin to my_app/next_level/admin?  Basically, I just wanna change the url to get to the admin dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this?

You can use a different URL scope for RailsAdmin by changing

`mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'`  in your config/routes.rb. e.g. You could do

`mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/foo_admin', ....`

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Troubleshoot